# I want to combine two Javascript Array with Lodash (not concat)

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have two array like below

```
  const registers = [{ user: 'Allen', type: 'phone' }, { user: 'Eric', type: 'email' }];
  const dates = ['20171225', '20180914'];
```

and I want they comebine like this

```
const result = [
  { user: 'Allen', type: 'phone', date: '20171225' }
  { user: 'Allen', type: 'phone', date: '20180914' }
  { user: 'Eric', type: 'email', date: '20171225' }
  { user: 'Eric', type: 'email', date: '20180914' }
];
```

I think there is an proper function of `Lodash` to use in this case,
but I can't find it by myself.
Is there any cool geek can help to get out of this hell. Thanks~

Comment: Is using lodash *required*? It's trivial to accomplish in vanilla JS

Comment: I just want to write less code to accomplish  it.

Comment: length of both array will always be same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree to use of plugins instead of rewrite what people have made available. But when It's simple, using a plugin is complicating things, it's better to use the simplier soluce when there is one.

```js
const registers = [{
  user: 'Allen',
  type: 'phone',
}, {
  user: 'Eric',
  type: 'email',
}];

const dates = [
  '20171225',
  '20180914',
];

const arr = registers.reduce((tmp, x) => [
  ...tmp,

  ...dates.map(y => ({
    ...x,

    date: y,
  })),
], []);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Output is not the same with desired output :)

Comment: That's right!
but I think the variable of sample code can change like this
tmp => registerList,   x => register, y=> date

Answer (score 1):

One method is with reduce + forEach, but any double loop should work.

```js
const registers = [{ user: 'Allen', type: 'phone' }, { user: 'Eric', type: 'email' }];
const dates = ['20171225', '20180914'];
let answer = registers.reduce((acc, n) => {
  dates.forEach(x => {
    acc.push({user: n.user, type: n.type, date: x});
  });
  return acc;
 }, [])
 console.log(answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, use of *lodash* doesn't yield much code reduction (you could simply replace the calls to `_.map(a, ...)` with `a.map(...)`). But well, here goes:

```js
const registers = [{ user: 'Allen', type: 'phone' }, { user: 'Eric', type: 'email' }];
const dates = ['20171225', '20180914'];
  
const result = _.map(registers, ({ user, type }) => _.map(dates, (date) => ({ user, type, date })));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.core.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

As OP stated to use lodash , Here is a solution

**Lodash Variant**

```js
var registers = [{ user: 'Allen', type: 'phone' }, { user: 'Eric', type: 'email' }];
var dates = ['20171225', '20180914'];

let result = _.map(registers, function(value, index, _source){
  return _.extend(value, { date: (dates[index] || null)});
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.core.min.js"></script>
```

**Vanilla JS Variant**

```js
var registers = [{ user: 'Allen', type: 'phone' }, { user: 'Eric', type: 'email' }];
var dates = ['20171225', '20180914'];

let result = registers.map(function(value, index, _source){
  return Object.assign(value, { date: (dates[index] || null)});
});

console.log(result);
```

**Updated Answer**

```js
var registers = [{ user: 'Allen', type: 'phone' }, { user: 'Eric', type: 'email' }];
var dates = ['20171225', '20180914'];

const result = _.flatten(_.map(registers, function(value, index, _source){
  return _.map(dates, (v, i, _s) => _.extend(value, { date: v})); 
}));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.core.js"></script>
```

Comment: please state a reason for downvote to help the person improve it.

Comment: I see that the snippet result is not matching with OP's request

Comment: Can you please justify, where is the difference? :-) As my solution & output both appears to be complying with the OP's requirement.  I posted vanilla js solution only but now updated it to use lodash as well.

Comment: Asked result contains 4 data at the end of it. There is an 'Allen' and an 'Eric' for every different dates. In the OP's example, two name + two date = 4 data

Comment: oops, I got it. Thank you ^